# python - loop break wont work second time

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def play_again():
    again = input("would you like to play another game? ").lower()
    while play_again:
        if again == "yes":
            play_again()
        elif again == "no":
            print("thank you for playing with us")
            break
        else:
            again = input("only yes, or no answers are allowed: ").lower()
            continue

play_again()
```

If I run the code and input no, code exits.

If I run the code and input `yes`, code continues, but if second input is `no`, code won't exit :(

can someone help me?

Comment: Yeah, because you're starting a second loop in a recursive function call. That second loop will end, at which point it'll resume with the first one…

Comment: In your own words, what exactly do you expect to happen when you call `play_again()` from inside `play_again()`? What do you expect to happen the next time the function returns? Why? Now, please read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science) and see if your understanding improves.

Comment: Please also read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: in my "real" code, the play_again() from inside play_again() calles a diffrent function to play another game, but if the secound time the player will choose no, it will open the game selection again without exiting

Comment: That probably doesn't really change the underlying logic. In `if again == "yes"`, you call a function. This loop here will then suspend until that function returns. It doesn't matter whether that's recursive or not. If and when that function returns, this loop will continue where it left off.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to those who replied, i removed the while loop and chose a diffrent way that now works:

```
    def play_again():
    again = input("would you like to play another game? ").lower()
    if again == "yes":
        play_again()
    elif again == "no":
        print("thank you for playing with us")
    else:
        print("only yes, or no answers are allowed")
        play_again()


play_again()
```